# Changing icon and title of partial trust WPF xbap

Tags: wpf, xbap

I've been fiddling with a partial trust XBAP - how can I change the icon shown in the IE-tab and the title (aside from changing the assembly-name in the project properties)?

I would also like to change what is shown in the Internet header (right now it shows the address of the XBAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your XBAP from a HTML page using an IFRAME.  In the HTML page add a title and icon.

Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is my title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://wherever.com/icon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe location="something.xbap"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; border:0; overflow:auto" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is simplified from code that I actually use, except due to some other requirements I'm giving the iframe an id and setting its location using JavaScript in the body's onload event.  I assume the above will work just as well.

Comment: Ahh great! Turns out I was looking in all the wrong places :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I could not change the title in IE 10 (this was the first stack overflow answer that comes up when you Google "xbap title"). I found the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e10572a-1379-4a1a-b4f5-9479215cfffd/setting-the-name-of-the-xbap-application-in-the-ie7-tabitem-header):

In code, set `Application.Current.MainWindow.Title` to the title you want to show. This worked for me, hopefully this will be helpful for the next guy.